# MYSQL Out Parameter will always return null for select query

Tags: mysql

I am new to MYSQL i want to return the out parameter value for the select query but it will always return null.
I have did a sample please take a look and kindly suggest me how to resolve this problem.

`SET`    ->  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0195c/1 
`SELECT` ->  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed9c82/1

Yes its working fine, but its my actual query

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SignIn`(IN p_strUsername varchar(100), IN p_strPassword varchar(100), out p_UserID long)
BEGIN
    select p_UserID = User.Id from User 
    inner join UserInfo on User.Id = UserInfo.UserID
    where User.UserName =p_strUsername and 
    user.Password = SHA1(p_strPassword);

```
select p_UserID;
```

END

Please suggest me. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing assignment in select statement.

You can set the value using set statement,.
First set the value like

```
SET <variablename> = <value>;
```

then

```
SELECT <variable name>;
```

check this
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e1cc/1

To assign value in variable suing SELECT,
You can do this like

```
SELECT <colname>,<colname> ..INTO <variable>, <variable> from <tbl>.
```

Comment: yes your query executes fine. But my actual query i have posted with my question which will always return null.

Comment: what is this " select p_UserID = User.Id" ?, and why?

Comment: To set the Output parameter to the P_USERID.

Comment: I have already tried without declaration it will also return null. so that i tried using (" select p_UserID = User.Id" ..).

Comment: try "select User.Id INTO p_UserID". to assign value into variable.

Comment: I have include one more out parameter and as well as i have added the User.Id into p_UserID, IsDisabled into P_IsDisabled. It will throw compile error (Error: syntax error, unexpected into, expecting ';' and pointing this "IsDisabled into P_IsDisabled" line ).   Please suggest me.

Comment: i have updated my answer, i think you should  check that. "select col1,col2,col3 INTO var1,var2, var3".. respectivly